# Asyncsocket disconnection event in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am working on the Asyncsocket client in iOS.

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

How do I know when the socket connection between server and client is broken ?

What delegate method should I use to detect disconnection ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read AsyncSocket.h, the following is very near the top (the first callback will actually give you information on the reason for the disconnection which can be useful)

```
/**
 * In the event of an error, the socket is closed.
 * You may call "unreadData" during this call-back to get the last bit of data off the socket.
 * When connecting, this delegate method may be called
 * before"onSocket:didAcceptNewSocket:" or "onSocket:didConnectToHost:".
**/
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock willDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)err;

/**
 * Called when a socket disconnects with or without error.  If you want to release a socket after it disconnects,
 * do so here. It is not safe to do that during "onSocket:willDisconnectWithError:".
 * 
 * If you call the disconnect method, and the socket wasn't already disconnected,
 * this delegate method will be called before the disconnect method returns.
**/
- (void)onSocketDidDisconnect:(AsyncSocket *)sock;
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you use the delegate method:

```
- (void)onSocketDidDisconnect:(AsyncSocket *)sock;
```

Comment: I think none of these methods gets invoked, when server closes. :( I have no idea how to know about server is being closed.